# Is it possible to convert a BigDecimal to Hexadecimal?

Tags: java, hex, biginteger, bigdecimal

Basically title. I know you can convert BigInteger to Hex by doing BigInteger.toString(16), but you can't do the same to a BigDecimal. Is there any easy way to do this? And if not, is there a way to increase/decrease a BigInteger by a percentage?

Comment: Just curious, how would you note a decimal number as a hexvalue? (i.e. How should `6.235` be written in hexadecimals)? It is usually a format used for integer values only. So either convert the BigDecimal to a BigInteger first, or use any other `toString` type methods (there are several notations available).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(10.0001)
String hexadecimal = bd.toBigInteger().toString(16);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this has the possibility to lose precesion! (a BigDecimal can be much larger than a native integer). Its better to use `BigDecimal.toBigInteger().toString()` or if fractional numbers shouldn't be allowed `BigDecimal.toBigIntegerExact().toString()`

Comment: In your first line of code, creating a `BigDecimal` from a `double` introduces the very [floating-point inaccuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) the class is meant to avoid. In your second line of code, getting a `double` from your `BigDecimal` again introduces floating-point inaccuracy. Such an output may not match the actual value of the `BigDecimal`.